# Linux `alloc_pages_node` not incrementing `_refcount` for all allocated pages

Tags: linux-kernel

When allocating physically-contiguous memory with `alloc_pages_node` in Linux v6.0, the `_refcount` in `struct page` for all of the allocated pages is not incremented. Only the first page of the allocation has its `_refcount` correctly incremented.

- Is this correct/intended behavior?
- Is this function only intended to be used in particular use cases/in a particular way such that the incorrect `_refcount` is accounted for?

Context: `alloc_pages*` are a series of functions in the kernel intended for allocating a physically contiguous set of pages [Documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v6.0/core-api/mm-api.html?highlight=kmalloc#c.alloc_pages). These functions return a pointer to the `struct page` corresponding to the first page of the allocated region.
I am using this function during early boot (in fact while setting up the stacks for the `init` process and for `kthreadd`).
By this point, the buddy-allocator is functional and usable.
Similar APIs (ignoring the need for physical contiguity) such as `vmalloc` increment the `_refcount` for all allocated pages.

This is the code I am running. The output is also listed below.

###### Code

```c
order = get_order(nr_pages << PAGE_SIZE);
p = alloc_pages_node(node, gfp_mask, order);
if (!p)
    return;
for(i =  0; i < nr_pages; i++, p++) 
    printk("_refcount = %d", p->_refcount);
```

###### Output

```
_refcount = 1
_refcount = 0
_refcount = 0
...
```

###### Arguments

`gfp_mask` is `(THREADINFO_GFP & ~__GFP_ACCOUNT) | __GFP_NOWARN | __GFP_HIGHMEM`.

- The first part `THREADINFO_GFP & ~__GFP_ACCOUNT` of this is sent by `alloc_thread_stack_node`
- `__vmalloc_area_node` adds `__GFP_NOWARN | __GFP_HIGHMEM`

`order = get_order(nr_pages << PAGE_SIZE) = 2` since `nr_pages` is 4.

Comment: What are the values of `gfp_mask` and `order`? This is very relevant information you should add.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm modifying the question to add this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this correct/intended behavior?

Yes, this is normal. Page allocations of order higher than 0 are effectively considered as a single "high-order" page<sup>**(1)**</sup> by the the buddy allocator, so functions such as `alloc_pages()` and `__free_pages()`, which operate on both order-0 and high-order pages, only care about the reference count of the first page.

Upon allocation (`alloc_pages`), only the first `struct page` of the group gets its refcount initialized. Upon deallocation (`__free_pages`), the refcount of the first page is decremented and tested: if it reaches zero, the whole group of pages gets actually freed<sup>**(2)**</sup>. When this happens, a sanity check is also performed on every single page to ensure that the reference count is zero.

If you intend to allocate multiple pages at once, but then manage them separately, you will need to split them using [`split_page()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.0/source/mm/page_alloc.c#L3585), which effectively "enables" reference counting for every single `struct page` and initializes its refcount to 1. You can then use `__free_pages(p, 0)` (or `__free_page()`) on each page separately.<sup>**(3)**</sup>

> Similar APIs (ignoring the need for physical contiguity) such as `vmalloc` increment the `_refcount` for all allocated pages.

Whether to allocate single order-0 pages or do a higher-order allocation is a choice that depends on the semantics of the specific memory allocation API. Problem is, these semantics can often change based on the actual API usage in kernel code<sup>**(4)**</sup>. Indeed as of now `vmalloc()` [splits the high-order page](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.0/source/mm/vmalloc.c#L2970) obtained from `alloc_pages()` using `split_page()`, but [this was only a recent change](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=3b8000ae185cb068adbda5f966a3835053c85fd4) done because some of its callers were relying on the allocated pages to be independent (e.g., doing their own reference counting).

---

<sup>**(1)** Not to be confused with [compound pages](https://lwn.net/Articles/619514/), although their refcounting is performed in the same way, i.e. only the first page (`PageHead()`) is refcounted.</sup>

<sup>**(2)** It is actually a little bit more complex than that, all pages except the first are freed regardless of the refcount of the first, to avoid memory leaks in rare situations, see [this relevant commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=e320d3012d25b1fb5f3df4edb7bd44a1c362ec10). The refcount sanity check on all the freed pages is done anyway.</sup>

<sup>**(3)** Note that allocating high-order pages and then splitting them into order-0 pages is generally not a good idea, as you can guess from the comment on top of `split_pages()`: *"Note: this is probably too low level an operation for use in drivers. Please consult with lkml before using this in your driver."* - This is because high-order allocations are harder to satisfy than order-0 allocations, and breaking high-order page blocks only makes it even harder.</sup>

<sup>**(4)** Welcome to the magic world of kernel APIs I guess. Much like Hogwarts' staircases, they like to change.</sup>

Comment: thanks for the brilliant reply. You've also added the clean way to handle refcounting for all but the first page, something for which I wrote my own workaround. Super! Btw, pleased to encounter a mHackeroni in the wild

Comment: While I realize that the code is the ultimate documentation, is there any more text-like documentation which explains this philosophy?

Comment: @TSG there are definitely documentation resources talking about `alloc_pages` (e.g. [here on Linux kernel archives](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand009.html))... but none of the ones I found explicitly mentions the fact that pages of high-order allocations are to be handled in bulk and not singularly, even though this has always been the case. The point is that you shouldn't really be allocating high-order pages and then splitting them into single ones, you should allocate multiple order-0 pages instead. High-order allocations are (intuitively) harder to satisfy.